# getting URL's from text

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

what is the easiest way of scanning a block of text, and if there is a URL, or more than one in there, grabbing the first one and following the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSDataDetector (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to locate the URLs by enumerating matches in an NSString. Pick up the first one and load the URL. (You didn't define what "follow" means in your context.)

Sorry, on my iPhone, so I apologize for any typos. :-)

Comment: Yes, your answer is better than my brute force one (so +1 to you).  And the O.P., [the documentation link even has a bit of sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to show how to get the URL via `NSTextCheckingTypeLink`.

Comment: Just saw your comment. Thanks! (And please don't take my comment too harshly... I've written more than my fair share of brute force code.)

Comment: I wasn't (too) offended Conrad ;-)  Part of the reason I participate here is to learn new stuff and my "spider sense" was tingling when I typed up my original (and now deleted) answer, as I had a feeling there was something available in the OS I just wasn't yet aware of.